# Trying to convert code to store comma separated string of enums

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I am trying to convert the following:

```
public IEnumerable<string> MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Record.MyProperty)) return new string[] { };
        return Record
            .MyProperty
            .Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(r => r.Trim())
            .Where(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r));
    }
    set { Record.MyProperty = value == null ? null : String.Join(",", value); }
}
```

to deal with an `enum`, but am failing epicly (is that a word?).

I was trying something like this:

```
string.Split(new[] ',', Record.MyProperty).Select
    (r => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), r));
```

to do the parsing, but again "epicly failing".

Any guidance? Thanks.

**Update:**

I am trying to persist this data as a `string`. So if the user selects three of four `enums`, it will save as a string thusly: "Choice1, Choice2, Choice3".

The above code is a proxy for `public string MyProperty { get; set; }`

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to change the type of the property to `IEnumerable<MyEnum>`?

Comment: In what way is it failing, other than "epicly"... :)

Comment: Yes, detail are more useful then adjectives.

Comment: @DrewNoakes well, that last bit of code I am getting "no best type found for implicitly-typed array" on the `new[]` portion. If I put `IEnumerable<MyEnum>`, then when I try to set the record like this: `record.MyProperty = new []...` I get the error "cannot implicitly convert string[] to IEnumerable<MyEnum>". Essentially, I don't know how to cast/convert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add some braces around the array you pass to `Split`, and call it as an instance method, not a static.

```
Record.MyProperty.Split(',')
                 .Select(r => (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), r));
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: No. I get a "Best overload method match for 'String.Split(char[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments" error. Just don't know how to write the code to get this right.